# Attribute android:id is not allowed here in new kotlin project in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, kotlin

I get errors in new Android Studio project in Kotlin connected with attributes:
'Attribute android:x is not allowed here"

file: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" #here
    android:layout_width="match_parent" #here
    android:layout_height="match_parent" #here
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" #here
    tools:openDrawer="start"> #here

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" #here
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> #here

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView #here
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try syncing project with Gradle files: `File` -> `Sync project with Gradle files`.

Answer (score 1):

In your root element, replace:

```
xmlns:android="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

with:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Also, remove `xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your root element.

Comment: @Barburka: OK, I found another problem -- see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rebuild or clean your project? I think you should try that then run the app again